# Why does this stop running early?

Tags: c, arrays, numbers

I'm actually working on a [projecteuler.com problem (#12 specifically)](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12) and I thought I had this nailed when I wasn't getting any compile errors.
It runs and gives me several results that appear to be correct, but it's not finishing.  I haven't been using C all that long so I am probably overlooking something I'm just not familiar with. Can someone tell me why it's stopping? It is giving me correct triangle numbers up to 12.5M. I would also gladly accept optimization suggestions in the comments.
The results are first, even after a few hours it didn't move on past the first number with 30 factors, which it found rather quickly.
It gives me this, from the code following it:

```
$ ./euler12
Current= 1
Factors= 1
Current= 3
Factors= 2
Current= 6
Factors= 4
Current= 28
Factors= 6
Current= 36
Factors= 9
Current= 120
Factors= 16
Current= 300
Factors= 18
Current= 528
Factors= 20
Current= 630
Factors= 24
Current= 1008
Factors= 30
```

where Current gives me the number it got the factors from and obviously then Factors is the number of factors. I doesn't give me any errors and the only warning from -Wall is that I don't actually use the "useless" variable for anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
/*
Tristen
euler12.c
December 23, 2013

What's the value of the first triangle number to have over 500 divisors?
*/
int main(void)
{
    /*---------Variables----------*/
    time_t t1 = time(NULL);
    int g,l,i,j,k,t,number,val,flag1,flag2;
    int h=1,x=0,p=0,n=5000,m=500,m2=600,twitch=0
    int answer=0,count=0,useless=0,linlen=0; /*modify n to change size*/
    /*----------Arrays------------*/
    int numtocheck[n];
    int factors[m2];
    /*find triangle numbers*/
    for(i=0;i<=n+1;i++){
        x+=i;
        if(x!=0){
            numtocheck[i]=x;
        }
        else{
            useless=0;
        }
    }
    /*begin checking for factors*/
    while(twitch!=1){
        count=0;
        for(l=1;l<m2;l++){
            factors[l]=0;
        }
        number=numtocheck[h];
        for(j=0;j<=number;j++){
            for(k=0;k<=number;k++){
                val=j*k;
                if(val==number){
                    flag1=0,flag2=0;
                    for(g=0;g<m2;g++){
                        if(factors[g]==j){
                            flag1=1;
                        }
                        else if(factors[g]==k){
                            flag2=1;
                        }
                        else{
                            useless=0;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag1==0){
                        factors[p]=j;
                    p+=1;
                    }
                    else if(flag2==0){
                        factors[p]=k;
                        p+=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        useless=0;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        for(l=0;l<m2;l++){
            if(factors[l]!=0){
                count+=1;
            }
        }
        if(count>=m){
            answer=number;
            printf("Current= %d\n",number);
            printf("Factors= %d\n",linlen);
            twitch=1;    
        }
        else{
           if(count>linlen){
                linlen=count;
                printf("Current= %d\n",number);
                printf("Factors= %d\n",linlen);
           }
           else{
                useless=0;
           }  
        }
        h+=1;
    }
    time_t t2 = time(NULL);
    t=t2-t1;
    printf("Survey says %d\n", answer);
    printf("time %d\n", t);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could step through this line-by-line with a debugger, in order to determine what it's doing (and why).

Comment: The first `for` loop accesses an invalid position in `numtocheck` when `i == n || i == n+1`; the test `x != 0` will evaluate to true and you will asign `x` to `numtocheck[n]` and in the next iteration you do the same for `numtocheck[n+1]`, you have an out-of-bounds error.

Comment: int numtocheck[n]; so the size is n but in the for loop ; for(i=0;i<=n+1;i++)... probably you should get segmentation fault as it is from stackspace it might be over-writing data on factors array

Comment: It wasn't giving me any faults, but I changed it just to make sure to this:

Comment: sorry, to this:  for(i=0;i<n;i++){  , but there is no change in behavior

Comment: And nothing seems funny when using gdb, except that it doesn't find any more still after 1008. I'm not very experienced with using a debugger though, so maybe I'm just not any good with it. :)

Comment: Take a look where you increment the `count` variable because it looks like, after some point, `count` becomes less than or equal to `linlen` so it cannot satisfy (`count > linlen`). You increment `count` when an integer from `factors` array is not equal to 0. So you should inspect that whether you change `factors`' elements in the true way.

Btw, you can do it in much more efficient way. When you finish it, just check some other solutions from Problem 12 Thread of PE Forum.

Comment: Since you asked about efficiencies, I can tell you that computing the summation itself can be done by simply `(i*(i+1))/2`. After that, you can double-up factors by remembering that any divisor will have a mate on *both* sides of the square root of your prospect, and if the number is a perfect square, will have one more after that. Given those two attributes this problem becomes *considerably* simpler than you're making it. [See it live](http://ideone.com/fPVcZ3)

Comment: @WhozCraig,I originally planned to do that latter part with the square root, but thought taking the root would be expensive, but now that I think about it, you're absolutely right for such large $n$ it would take less time for the square root than to cycle through $(n)^2$ instead of $n$.  A lot of my attempt was spent trying to avoid division.  I've been trying to practice avoiding it through my numerical analysis class and next semester I plan to expand my knowledge of these many little tricks and such as I'm going to be doing some research in primes and factorization.  Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some points to consider (point 5 is the big problem):

1) you forgot a semicolon so this code won't compile, based on this, I'm a little concerned you don't have everything in here verbatim to how you have it...

```
int h=1,x=0,p=0,n=5000,m=500,m2=600,twitch=0  //<- ; needed
```

2) as noted in the comments your first for loop overflows the array:

```
int n=5000;
int numtocheck[n];

/* so numtocheck[] goes from 0 to 4999 */

/*find triangle numbers*/
for(i=0;i<=n+1;i++){     // this loops from 0 to 5001
```

So this needs to be:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
```

3) since you don't initialize the 0<sup>th</sup> element of `numtocheck` that means there is garbage data in `numtocheck[0]`. Same thing later for `factors[0]`, the latter is OK since you over write it, but it's just something to be careful about.

4) You use `useless` to avoid empty `else` cases... this is, as you aptly named it, useless. If you don't have anything to do, don't do anything.

For example instead of writing this:

```
       if(count>linlen){
            linlen=count;
            printf("Current= %d\n",number);
            printf("Factors= %d\n",linlen);
       }
       else{
            useless=0;
       }
```

Just remove the `else`, a `if` ***can*** be paired with an `else`, it does not ***need*** to be.

5) OK, here's the *big* problem:

```
                if(flag1==0){
                    factors[p]=j;
                p+=1;
                }
                else if(flag2==0){
                    factors[p]=k;
                    p+=1;
                }
```

`factors[]` is an array of 600 elements, and you access using `p` a value that's initially 0 but is incremented every time it enters either of these checks. By the time your `number` is around 2346 `p` more than overflows the 600 elements in `factors[]` and you start doing bad things. This causes undefined behavior. On one implantation in Linux this caused a very nice setfault. On a different one in Windows this simply over wrote the values in `numtocheck` basically making you go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Mike, thank you, that's got tobe the most helpful information I've gotten from anyone for C.  I'm currently working on learning C and C++.  Most everything I've worked on in the past is with python.  I try not to make too many assumptions, like not needing the else statement.  I was thinking that I hadread that it had to be there for some reason. Again, thanks a bunch.